# PHP - Highlight character(s) in string

Tags: php, string, text, formatting

I'm currently working on a search function for my website.

When the user is searching 'Test', and someone's name is 'besttest', for example, the 'test' in 'besttest' should be in another color. But only the 'test', not the whole word.

I've tried to figure it out myself, but I didn't get it working.

Hope you guys and girls can help me ^^

Comment: Yes, because it's with databases. It's fine for me.

Comment: Just use str_replace and insert html in the string. `str_replace($search, "<b>" . $search . "</b>", $string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function. The example below will highlight just the keywork wish is "Test" in this case not the whole word. Try this code, really it will help you.

```
 $str = "besttest";
 $keyword = "Test";
 $str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i",'<span class="yellow">$1</span>',$str);
 print($str);
```

this will output something like this :

```
best<span class="yellow">test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes only sense, if you use a markup language... but here's an approach:

```
$lookup = [
    'test' => '<span class="red">%s</span>',
    'color' => '<span class="green">%s</span>',
    '[0-9]+' => '<b>%s</b>',
];


$string = 'This is a test for coloring testwise an uncolored test-value. Testing 950 349 2 numbers... ';
echo 'before: "'. $string.'"'.PHP_EOL;

foreach($lookup as $term => $format) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/'.$term.'/', function($matches) use($format) {
        return sprintf($format, $matches[0]);
    }, $string);
}
echo 'after: "'. $string.'"'.PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
before: "This is a test for coloring testwise an uncolored test-value. Testing 950 349 2 numbers... "
after: "This is a <span class="red">test</span> for <span class="green">color</span>ing <span class="red">test</span>wise an un<span class="green">color</span>ed <span class="red">test</span>-value. Testing <b>950</b> <b>349</b> <b>2</b> numbers... "
```

With regular expressions, you can match pretty much anything possible and give it different styles...

hth

Comment: Thanks! It works but the solution of Amine KOUIS is better for me in this situation :)